# How to display multiple images in Unix command line?

Tags: image, unix

I have 17 .png images I would quite like to look at at the same time so as to compare them. Is there a Unix command that displays all of them together? I have tried researching this but can't seem to find anything!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could append them all together side-by-side into a combined image with **ImageMagick** which is in most Linux distros:

```
convert *.png -append BigBoy.jpg
```

[image]

Then use `feh` or whatever viewer you like to view `BigBoy.jpg`. Change `-append` to `+append` to join them top-to-bottom instead of side-to-side.

Or if you wanted them in a grid 4 images across, use `montage` like this:

```
montage -tile 4x -geometry +0+0 *.png montage.jpg
```

[image]

Or use the flicker_compare script from the ImageMagick website [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/scripts/flicker_cmp) like this:

```
flicker_cmp -o a.gif *.png
```

[image]

Comment: Worked a treat, thank you! I am relatively new to Unix :P

Comment: My pleasure! Questions are free, so ask away and enjoy the power of Unix.